# Android - Porting C++ Socket Server to Android?

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-ndk

I'm newbie to Android development, but I am linux c/c++ background guy.

Now, I have linux c++ network proxy program, which is TCP Server and Client written in boost library. The function of this proxy program is

1. TCP server will receive Android app's request, and translate that
   request to some specific format
2. then behave as client to send out translated thing to correct remote computer (like router)

My task is to porting this program on Android system. And hope the Android native application communicates with this proxy program through socket like in Linux.

I search the web, try to find the proper way to do this. But, it seems that most of existing things I found are java JNI library based solution.

I wonder if this could be done in daemon or service process way. The proxy program is a bit large, so, re-write is a real pain for me.

Any suggestion or solution would be highly appreciated. Thanks advance!

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Unless we are talking about rooted devices, there is no way around on having to deal with Java on Android, at some level in the stack.

You can wrap your code in a Native Activity, which basically means an existing Android Java class that knows how to load a set of predefined public symbols from an .so file.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#native-application-apis

The problem here would be when to launch the said activity, as there is no guarantee to keep it running.

Android doesn't have daemons on the UNIX sense, only services.

So as alternative you could create an Android service class, however starting with version 8, there are execution restrictions. Meaning you cannot have it run forever on the background.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Possibly by using a bound service, which the applications would need to connect to before talking via sockets might do what you need.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services